# Changing typeface of Snackbar

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I build Snackbar by this code:

```
Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(drawer,  "message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
       .setAction("action", new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

       }
});
```

Now I want to change the typeface of message and action button but can't find any solution, How to do that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can set TypeFace by getting view from Snack bar

```
TextView tv = (TextView) (mSnackBar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/font_file.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

For AndroidX, use resource ID `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`

Answer (score 15):

#### Styling Both the Snackbar Text and Action

You can use the same method to style both the `snackbar_text` and `snackbar_action`.

Once you've created a snackbar, you can use the following to get the Views associated with the text and the action and then apply whatever adjustments to the view.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make( ... )    // Create the Snackbar however you like.

TextView snackbarActionTextView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById( android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action );
snackbarActionTextView.setTextSize( 20 );
snackbarActionTextView.setTypeface(snackbarActionTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

TextView snackbarTextView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
snackbarTextView.setTextSize( 16 );
snackbarTextView.setMaxLines( 3 );
```

In my example, I've set the Action to be font size 20 and Bold, and the Text to be size 16 and allow up to 3 lines.

Answer (score 15):

For **AndroidX**

`android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text` won't be available.

> **Use** `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`instead.

**If you are using kotlin**, then I prefer you to use extension function:

```
fun Snackbar.changeFont()
{
    val tv = view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
    val font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "your_font.ttf")
    tv.typeface = font
}
```

and call it like:

```
mSnakeBar.changeFont()
```

Comment: createFromAsset didn't work for me and the app crashed every time saying that it can't find my font i used getFont from ResourceCompat like this
`val font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.my_font)`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36800051/7913069): now package to find snackbar's textview by id is

```
val snackText = snackView.findViewById<TextView>(
                    com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Get the snack bar view and apply customization**

```
TextView tv = (TextView) sb.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(
                    getAssets(),
                    "fonts/ur_file.ttf"));
```

**Or this**

```
SpannableStringBuilder snackbarText = new SpannableStringBuilder();
snackbarText.append("Add ");
int boldStart = snackbarText.length();
snackbarText.append("bold color");
snackbarText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFF0000), boldStart, snackbarText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
snackbarText.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), boldStart, snackbarText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
snackbarText.append(" to Snackbar text");

Snackbar.make(view, snackbarText, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or you can give a look at [this](https://github.com/nispok/snackbar) and [this](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/material-design-snackbar-using-the-design-support-library/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from **Support Library 26**, fonts can be used as **resources**.

```
val mainTextView = view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
val font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(applicationContext, R.font.your_font)
mainTextView.typeface = font
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still reading this 7 years later, you can change the text appearance of the snackbar for the whole app by overriding its theme parent in your themes.xml file.

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.App.SnackbarTextView</item>
</style>


<style name="Widget.App.SnackbarTextView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/your_snackbar_text_style</item>
</style>
```

And then in your styles.xml file insert the `your_snackbar_text_style` style there

```
    <style name="your_snackbar_text_style">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get assets

```
AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
```

Get Typeface

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets,PATH OF .TTF FILE);
```

Path: font/robotoregular.ttf (if .ttf file is stored in assets/font path)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the font of Action Button and textview use this code :

```
Snackbar.make(this,message,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).also {snackbar ->
  snackbar.setAction("ok"){
     snackbar.dismiss()
  }
  val actionButton = snackbar.view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action) as Button
  val textview = snackbar.view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
  val font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "fonts/your_custom_font")
  actionButton.typeface = font
  textview.typeface = font
  ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(snackbar.view,ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)
```

}.show()

Answer (score 0):

For every one that crashes when calling **createFromAsset()** you can use

```
Font font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getApplicationContext(), R.font.your_font);
```